# Adaptive Server connection timed out with FreeTDS

Tags: bash, t-sql, freetds

I have a bash script that reads from a remote MSSQL server 2008 using FreeTDS.

Using `tsql`, I am able to make individual queries and all of them run perfectly separately. However, when I run the bash script that contains multiple queries, I get the following error, after some successful queries:

```
Error 20003 (severity 6):
    Adaptive Server connection timed out
    OS error 115, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Here is my `freetds.conf`:

```
#...
[mssql]
    host = <my_ip>
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.3
```

Here is what my bash script looks like:

```
# ...
TDSVER=7.3 tsql -S mssql -U $USER -P $PASSWORD < $QUERY1_SQL > $OUT1.CSV
TDSVER=7.3 tsql -S mssql -U $USER -P $PASSWORD < $QUERY2_SQL > $OUT2.CSV
TDSVER=7.3 tsql -S mssql -U $USER -P $PASSWORD < $QUERY3_SQL > $OUT3.CSV
TDSVER=7.3 tsql -S mssql -U $USER -P $PASSWORD < $QUERY4_SQL > $OUT4.CSV
# ...
```

I read that the error i'm getting is likely due to wrong TDS version, but I don't think that is the case, since I can run each query individually from prompt and successfully get the results. I also tried using TDSVER=8.0, but without success.

I noticed that if I comment some random queries in the bash file, it works without any errors (not any specific queries, though, if I comment query1 and query2, for example it works, but if I leave query1 and query2 uncommented and comment query3 and query4, it also works). What is the problem here?

Comment: May be to add interval between each query execution using sleep command

Comment: Tried that, no success. Seems the connection isn't stable for some odd reason - I'm getting the feeling that the error occurs randomly

Comment: What if you exec same query 4 times in bash script?

Comment: @MuradTagirov, I get the same error

Comment: Or try to exec each query in separate bash? Just to check. May be after first exec tds driver somehow corrupts current shell environment.

Comment: I tried that, each query executes ok - maybe because there is no time to get an intermission?

Comment: So, now its work now? Not sure. May be some state of current shell in changing. Env variables for example.

Comment: It still doesn't work when all queries are in the bash script

Comment: No, I mean to exec each tsql command in your script in separate bash environment. Like following: bash -c "TDSVER=7.3 tsql -S mssql -U $USER -P $PASSWORD < $QUERY1_SQL > $OUT1.CSV"